# Mimic rsync command behaviour in shell script

Tags: shell, escaping, sh, rsync

I'm attempting to write my first short backup script. I'm using "plain" sh. When I issue the following command on the command line:

```
rsync /home/username/.* /home/username/backups
```

everything works well, as expected [IE ONLY my dotfiles and dot-directories are backed up].

But when I run a shell script with this line in it, rsync behaves strangely and ends up repeatedly and recursively backing up everything and my dotfiles. So I end up with a backup like this:

```
/backups/dotfiles/backups/dotfiles/backups/dotfiles/    etc etc etc.
```

How do I make use of the "*" in a this shell script to make rsync behave as expected?

Here is the whole script:

```
#!/bin/sh

#Backup dotfiles
echo 'Backing up dotfiles...'
rsync -avzu --delete --progress --exclude='.wine' --max-size='100M' /home/slowmo/.* /home/slowmo/backups/dotfiles/

#Compress into single file
echo 'Compressing dotfiles...'
tar cvzf /home/slowmo/backups/dotfiles.tar.gz /home/slowmo/backups/dotfiles/
```

Comment: Please post the exact code you are running. The recursive-looking directory you post looks like something you'd get if you have a variable whose value is empty when you think it contains an absolution path (e.g. `$VAR/backups/dotfiles` expanding to `/backups/dotfiles` instead of `/home/username/backups/dotfiles`). Also, it looks like a symlink could be involved.

Comment: And running the *exact* command from the script (`-avzu --delete` etc.) on the command line behaves differently? I don't see how running the command on the script should behave differently if you run it manually. Check to make sure none of the dot files (or files in a dot directory) is a symlink to `backups/` or `backups/dotfiles`.

Comment: Yup. They behave differently on my system [FreeBSD]. I've had this problem before actually; the "*" or "." seem to be causing problems from within the script. OK, I'll start checking. But I'm sure there shouldn't be a symlink. Is it possible to check by running a command to find any symlink pointing to "backups"?

Comment: What shell do you use?  It will probably be your shell doing the wildcard expansion, and it may behave differently when invoked as /bin/sh, even if it's the same shell.  Replacing your `#!/bin/sh` shebang line with the path to your actual shell may get it to behave the same way.   Alternatively, you could get rsync to do the wildcard expansion by wrapping the argument in quotes - i.e. `rsync "/home/username/.*" /home/username/backups`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly the same, but I just ran across a similar issue.

I saw different results when trying to back up my hidden files from my home directory using both:

- rsync from the shell - worked as expected, all dot files backed up when doing `rsync .* /media/backup/dotfiles`
- rsync from a bash script. The same command as above didn't work, backed up the dot files, but also every other folder in the home directory.

On some investigation and reflection it turns out my shell (`zsh`) expands wildcards differently to bash, and this difference is crucial in this particular case. `zsh` does **not** expand .* to include . (this directory) and ..  (parent directory), whereas `bash` does, so in the bash script rsync was given all hidden files, including the folder itself and the parent directory.

I've changed my script to instead call:

`rsync .[^.]* /media/backup/dotfiles`

which solves my problem - but do note that this pattern won't match regular files that start with `..`, like `..tmp`

Some places to look for more information (not always in the context of rsync) include:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/476265/180385
- https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-appleosx-bsd-rsync-copy-hidden-dot-files/
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90075/180385
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/685367/180385